# unexpected EOF while parsing Webscraping (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: beautifulsoup, webdriver, screen-scraping

I am trying to run this block code that is part of a WebScraping project of real estate data (https://github.com/arturlunardi/webscraping_vivareal/blob/main/scrap_vivareal.ipynb) but I am encountering errors in the card loop and cannot think of a solution (I am a beginner in the scraping part)

```
# Web-Scraping
    
for line in soup.findAll(class_="js-card-selector"):
      
        try:
            full_address=line.find(class_="property-card__address").text.strip()
            address.append(full_address.replace('\n', '')) #Get all address
            if full_address[:3]=='Rua' or full_address[:7]=='Avenida' or full_address[:8]=='Travessa' or full_address[:7]=='Alameda':
                neighbor_first=full_address.strip().find('-')
                neighbor_second=full_address.strip().find(',', neighbor_first)

                if neighbor_second!=-1:
                    neighbor_text=full_address.strip()[neighbor_first+2:neighbor_second]
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text) 
                else: # Bairro não encontrado
                    neighbor_text='-'
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text) 
            else:
                get_comma=full_address.find(',')

                if get_comma!=-1:
                    neighbor_text=full_address[:get_comma]
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text) 
                else:
                    get_hif=full_address.find('-')
                    neighbor_text=full_address[:get_hif]
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text)
```

```
File "/tmp/ipykernel_70908/2775873616.py", line 26
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: The issue is the code is incomplete. Where is the rest of the code? I see the `try:` statement. There should be an `except:` statement in line with the `try:`

Comment: EOF stands for end-of-file. So as I stated, the code is incomplete. The error says it was: `unexpected end-of-file while parsing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not running the full block of code. Every `try:` statement should be followed by an `except:`. The code in the github link has it. The code you are showing that you are running does not. That's why you get the error.

```
for line in soup.findAll(class_="js-card-selector"):
      
        try:
            full_address=line.find(class_="property-card__address").text.strip()
            address.append(full_address.replace('\n', '')) #Get all address
            if full_address[:3]=='Rua' or full_address[:7]=='Avenida' or full_address[:8]=='Travessa' or full_address[:7]=='Alameda':
                neighbor_first=full_address.strip().find('-')
                neighbor_second=full_address.strip().find(',', neighbor_first)

                if neighbor_second!=-1:
                    neighbor_text=full_address.strip()[neighbor_first+2:neighbor_second]
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text) 
                else: # Bairro não encontrado
                    neighbor_text='-'
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text) 
            else:
                get_comma=full_address.find(',')

                if get_comma!=-1:
                    neighbor_text=full_address[:get_comma]
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text) 
                else:
                    get_hif=full_address.find('-')
                    neighbor_text=full_address[:get_hif]
                    neighbor.append(neighbor_text)

        except:
            continue
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! It may seem like a stupid question, but as I said, I am still beginning to practice this part of Scraping. :)

Comment: not a stupid question. It's how we learn! now you know when you see that error it means something is incomplete or missing. Sometimes its an `except` statement or another statement. Alot of the times when I get that error, it's because I'm missing a closing `)`, `}` or `]` somewhere. So just something to be aware of in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips! I will keep practicing and paying attention to the details you mentioned